# I need assistance creating a reverse proxy for multiple ports on a Windows server using Nginx

Tags: nginx, windows-server-2012-r2, reverse-proxy

I have  never used Nginx before and have been tasked with configuring it as a reverse proxy to a website in the Production Lan. I have port 80 working but i also need port 443 and port 18081 to function as well to this same webserver. The Nginx server is a windows 2012 server with Mginx 1.17.9 running. I know this config is messy as i took one that was supposed to work for multiple ports and remarked out what i thought i didnt need in my situation. Any assistance would be appreciated in getting this to work to proxy all 3 ports to the inside server.  The URL that the outside users will be using is https://website.domain.com/mydealer/#/login/QS36F

```
#user  nobody;
worker_processes  1;

#error_log  logs/error.log;
#error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
#error_log  logs/error.log  info;

#pid        logs/nginx.pid;

 events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http{
 server{
     listen 80;
      server_name website.domain.com;

     location / {
       proxy_pass http://1.2.3.4/;
      #proxy_redirect off;
      #proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      #proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      #proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
      #proxy_set_header X-Nginx-Proxy true;

      #error_page  404              /404.html;

      # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
      #
      error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
      location = /50x.html {
          root   html;
      }
      # proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:80
      #
      #location ~ \.php$ {
      #    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;
      #}

      # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
      #
      #location ~ \.php$ {
      #    root           html;
      #    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
      #    fastcgi_index  index.php;
      #    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /scripts$fastcgi_script_name;
      #    include        fastcgi_params;
      #}

      # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
      # concurs with nginx's one
      #
      #location ~ /\.ht {
      #    deny  all;
      #}
  }


  # another virtual host using mix of IP-, name-, and port-based configuration
  #
  #server {
    listen       18081;
    #    listen       somename:8080;
    server_name website.domain.com;

    location / {
    proxy_pass http://1.2.3.4/;
    #        root   html;
    #        index  index.html index.htm;
    #    }
  #}

  # HTTPS server
  #
  #server {
      listen       443;
      server_name website.domain.com;

      location / {
        proxy_pass https://1.2.3.4/;

      #    ssl_certificate      cert.pem;
      #    ssl_certificate_key  cert.key;

      #    ssl_session_cache    shared:SSL:1m;
      #    ssl_session_timeout  5m;

      #    ssl_ciphers  HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
      #    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers  on;

      #    location / {
      #        root   html;
      #        index  index.html index.htm;
      #    }
    #}
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand well You want deploy nginx reverse proxy on your Windows 2012 server.

Where is your apache web server running? On same machine as nginx or other machine? How many apache web servers You got?

Be more specific please!

with regards
Boris

Comment: The apache server is running on an entirely different server. I am imply trying to pass requests along to the apache server in my LAn from the Proxy server in my DMZ. my firewall rules are in place and working but the only port that is being sent to the Apache server is 80. I need to make sure that 443 and 18081 are properly configured to be forwarded by Nginx as well.

Comment: Ok, few more questions.

Comment: Ok, few more questions. Do you need https from nginx to your apace server? Do you have ssl certificate in your apache server? Do you need https only from client to proxy or you need  https also from proxy to upstream apache server? Is it necessary for all your trafic which come to proxy to be encrypted, which is recommended if you handle with personal data or financial information.

Comment: I do need HTTPS from the Nginx to the Apache server. The developer has not provided the cert information\path as yet to me. My traffic coming into the Nginx is fine. I do a netstat -a and can see all the ports i need. I just need to get my config right so that Nginx passes it on to my Apache server.  All the examples i can find on the web deal with linux servers running Nginx so im unable to find a config that has windows paths to the certificates ( do they need to be local to the Nginx server for example) and how to pass these 3 specific ports along from Nginx to Apache.

Comment: client--http-->nginx--https-->apache  is this what you want?

Comment: Client --( http,https,18081) --> Nginx --( http,https,18081) --> Apache  is what i need to come through and have the Nginx reverse proxy to the Apache.